# Embedding Markdown in Jekyll HTML

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll

I'm trying to nest markdown in an HTML file while using Jekyll. Is there a way to achieve something like the following?

```
# index.html

---
layout: default
---


<p>[Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com)</p>
```

Note: I'm aware that I could do this instead.

```
# index.html

---
layout: default
---


<p><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a></p>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's how you can define a markdown block with a [Jekyll plugin](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/):

```
module Jekyll
  class MarkdownBlock < Liquid::Block
    def initialize(tag_name, text, tokens)
      super
    end
    require "kramdown"
    def render(context)
      content = super
      "#{Kramdown::Document.new(content).to_html}"
    end
  end
end
Liquid::Template.register_tag('markdown', Jekyll::MarkdownBlock)
```

(To install this snippet as a plugin, put it in a `*.rb` file under `_plugins` directory of your source site root)

Then, use it like this:

```
{% markdown %}
[Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com)
{% endmarkdown %}
```

*EDIT*: See @Cristian's answer for a better solution! If you're using Kramdown (which is likely the case since you are using Jekyll), you can use it's feature to render markdown inside `div`'s with a `markdown="1"` attribute.

Comment: note that I had to `gem install kramdown` for this.  It seems a little hacky not to use whatever Jekyll uses built-in for markdown parsing, but it does work!

Comment: Note also that `Document.new(content, input: 'GFM)` will enable github-flavored markdown for you.

Comment: @PeterEhrlich: Jekyll uses Kramdown as the default: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/configuration.rb#L37. But yes, it would be nicer to be able to delegate the call to *whatever-markdown-processor-is-used-in-the-current-config* somehow.

Comment: Could you please detail what to do with the block of code you've got at the start of this answer?

Comment: @detly, I've updated the answer with short installation instruction.

Comment: Does not work with:   
  {% markdown %}
  * TOC
  {:toc}
  {% endmarkdown %}

Comment: If you change `super` to `super.strip` inside of the render method it will allow you to indent your code. Otherwise the block can't be indented.

Answer (score 89):

If you are using Kramdown, based on [their doc](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#html-blocks) you can do this:

```
<div markdown="1">
   My text with **markdown** syntax
</div>
```

And this way, the text within the `div` is rendered as markdown.

Make sure to use the `.md` or `.markdown` extension for the file, as `.html` files aren't sent to Kramdown for processing!

Comment: Thank you fine sir, this is the cleanest solution proposed.

Comment: Becareful not having 4 spaces when indenting your HTML code, otherwise you will get `<pre>`, see https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown/issues/213

Comment: @PerLundberg I struggled to get this work too. Fiddled with everything!!! Finally I found this: http://ricostacruz.com/til/markdown-in-jekyll.html Long story short, rename `index.html` to `index.md`. Took me waaay too long to figure it out.

Comment: Works with jekyll 3.0 for me

Comment: Does not work in default.html with the minimal GitHub setup.

Comment: This method mostly worked, except that for some strange reason, it kept adding random `</div>` tags to my code, and sometimes, it would not finish the code, so everything else in the file got treated as code as well. Eventually, I found the following solution using `capture` to capture the code at the top of the file and inject it into the `{% highlight %}` tags later in the page: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38819797/85309

Comment: Considering that you have to use .md files, how is this different than without the surrounding `<div>` tag? Edit: nevermind, I get it--you can render markdown deep within HTML tags where it would normally be ignored by Kramdown.

Answer (score 15):

As of current Jekyll 3.6.2 life can be a lot simpler with the following two options:

[image]

```html
<div>
{{ "## Yes, this renders as markdown" | markdownify }}
</div>
```

*note the markdown-attribute:*

```html
<div markdown="1">
## some markdown
inside some html. `snippet` _italic_ **bold**
</div>
```

Comment: Should `markdown="1"` work on other elements, such as `display` or does it only work in a `div`?

Comment: I am unaware of a display element :P, but it should work on `<section>`, `<nav>`, `<main>` all the same…

Answer (score 9):

@sunny-juneja, check out the Liquid Extension Filter called `markdownify`:

https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/liquid-extensions#markdownify

Use it like this:

`<p>{{ '[Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com)' | markdownify }}</p>`

Put single or double quotes around your string inside of the *Output* tag.

Works for me on Jekyll 1.0.0beta3

Comment: This works for variables, but not if you want to import a separate markdown file or put markdown directly inside an HTML block. @MisterMetaphor's answer below to create a plugin solves that issue.

Comment: I don't think this will work. The output content will be `<p><p><p><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a></p>`.

Answer (score 8):

I just recently spent way too many hours trying to do something similar. @J.T.'s 2nd bullet point, referencing `markdownify`, is what ultimately got me moving in the right direction.

I had in my `_layouts` directory a few different layouts. One of them, I wanted to add a bit of an "index" before the page content. The index was working perfectly as a partial, if I called it directly from a page or post, but not when trying to add it to a layout.

Here's what I had:

```html
---
layout: default
---

<div class="table-of-contents">
  
  {% include series_index.md %}
  
  {{ content }}
</div>
```

But it wouldn't work. Instead of rendering HTML on the page, the `include` was spitting out the markdown, which was then being added to the page as an ugly block of markdown, instead of rendering the markdown as HTML.

So, I tried tacking `| markdownify` to the `include` statement, like so:

```html
  {% include jekyll-bug-fix-index.md | markdownify %}
```

and that didn't work.

### The solution, using a variable, a capture "block", and markdownify

So, I *captured* the markdown, saved to a variable, and then rendered the variable with the liquid `markdownify` tag:

```html
  {% capture index %}
  {% include series_index.md %}
  {% endcapture %}
  
  {{ index | markdownify }}
```

And this works! The Markdown is rendered as HTML on my pages, and all is right in the world.

I have no doubt this is unconventional, and I hope to someday learn a better solution, but it's 100% good enough for me, and I wanted to share so others might benefit from this.

Comment: You made my day ^^

Comment: @Josh_Thompson: Thank you! I came closest with the help of your answer. 
But parts of my markdown(mainly links) are still not rendered properly. 

I use markdown instead of HTML for content with many links and I have been struggling to include that using  jekyll.

Answer (score 5):

To convert the `markdown-formatted` string to HTML in a Jekyll page, there are `THREE WAYS` can be selected as below:

### 1. Kramdown:

If you are using **Kramdown**, based on [their doc](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#html-blocks) you can do this:

```html
<div markdown="1">
## Some Markdown Title
Let's have a look. `snippet` _italic_ **bold**
</div>
```

The `markdown` attribute:

- If an HTML tag has an attribute markdown="0", then the tag is parsed as raw HTML block.
- If an HTML tag has an attribute markdown="1", then the default mechanism for parsing syntax in this tag is used.
- If an HTML tag has an attribute markdown="block", then the content of the tag is parsed as block level elements.
- If an HTML tag has an attribute markdown="span", then the content of the tag is parsed as span level elements.

Requirments:

- The markdown content need to be within the `DIV tag`.
- Make sure to use the `.md` or `.markdown` extension for the file
  as .html files aren't sent to Kramdown for processing)

### 2. Liquid Extension Filter

There is a liquid extension filter called **[markdownify](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/)**, it also can help you convert a Markdown-formatted string into HTML.

```
<div>
{{ "Renders as markdown. `snippet` _italic_ **bold**" | markdownify }}
</div>
```

### 3. Jekyll plugin:

> jekyll-spaceship -  A Jekyll plugin to provide powerful supports for table, mathjax, mermaid, plantuml, emoji, youtube, vimeo, dailymotion, etc.

https://github.com/jeffreytse/jekyll-spaceship

With this plugin, it's easy to write markdown inside HTML:

```html
<script type="text/markdown">
# Hybrid HTML with Markdown is a not bad choice ^\_^

##2. Table Usage

| :        Fruits \|\| Food       : |||
| :--------- | :-------- | :--------  |
| Apple      | :  Apple :| Apple      \
| Banana     |   Banana  | Banana     \
| Orange     |   Orange  | Orange     |
| :   Rowspan is 4    : || How's it?  |
|^^    A. Peach         ||   1. Fine :|
|^^    B. Orange        ||^^ 2. Bad   |
|^^    C. Banana        ||  It's OK!  |

## PlantUML Usage

@startuml
Bob -> Alice : hello
@enduml

## Video Usage

![](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ptk_1Dc2iPY)
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Paul Irish's Gist](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1343518) for a JS code that can interpret sections of your page from Markdown to HTML.

Comment: This is really cool. I was hoping for a jekyll specific solution but I'll mark you as an answer if no one provides one.

Comment: If this gist ever goes away, this answer won't be useful to future visitors. Placing the content in this answer while still providing a link to the original will keep this answer useful forever