# Embedding Markdown in blockquote plugin in Octopress

Tags: jekyll, octopress, jekyll-extensions

I like the functionality of the blockquote plugin for Octopress (http://octopress.org/docs/blogging/plugins/). It would give me a nice way of attributing the quote to the author.

However, I could not figure out how to blockquote content that is in markdown.

Here is an example of what I tried:

```
{% blockquote Author http://sourceurl.com %}

[Octopress](http://octopress.org/) is a blogging framework written by [Brandon Mathis](http://brandonmathis.com/)
([@imathis](https://twitter.com/#!/imathis)) which sits on top of [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll). Jekyll is
a static site generator, meaning there's no database associated with your blog. Instead of writing everything in a

{% endblockquote %}
```

Any advice? It seems something like this might work: [Embedding Markdown in Jekyll HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917463/embedding-markdown-in-jekyll-html)

I've got this on a github octopress deploy right here: http://www.railsonmaui.com and you can find the source to this article here: https://github.com/justin808/justin808.github.io/blob/source/source/_posts/2013-04-27-octopress-setup-with-github-and-org-mode.markdown

(Octopress freely deployed on github is seriously cool, especially with org-mode)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `{% raw %} ... {% endraw %}` tags. This will prevent the enclosed content from being parsed.