# How to remove unnecessary indent and break line in highlight jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I use jekyll `code highlight` with `gem rouge`.

[Templates - Jekyll • Simple, blog-aware, static sites](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/)

### Code (index.html)

```
---
layout: default
---

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:red;">
      {% highlight ruby %}
      def hoge
        puts 'red'
      end
      {% endhighlight %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:blue;">
      {% highlight ruby %}
      def foo
        puts 'blue'
      end
      {% endhighlight %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:yellow;">
      {% highlight ruby %}
def bar
  puts 'yellow'
end
      {% endhighlight %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Result

[image]

### Commit

https://github.com/shingo-nakanishi/jekyll-dojo/tree/ca564cd5653e7ee028cd30b87c04a6076f078693

### Point

```
      {% highlight ruby %}
def bar
  puts 'yellow'
end
      {% endhighlight %}
```

is the unnecessary indent was gone. but unreadable html code. the unnecessary break line not gone.

How to remove them?

Comment: Did you have a repository url ? It's better for debugging.

Comment: I edit for commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The newlines and extra indentation are being preserved inside the `highlight` tags - similar to how text inside an HTML `pre` tag is displayed by default. The first newline is trimmed, but the final newline is preserved since it is followed by whitespace.

This produces the output you want, at the cost of source indentation:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    ...
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:yellow;">
{% highlight ruby %}
def bar
  puts 'yellow'
end
{% endhighlight %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could capture the output above your markup to keep your source indentation:

```
{% capture code %}
def bar
  puts 'yellow'
end
{% endcapture %}

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    ...
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:yellow;">
      {% highlight ruby %}{{ code }}{% endhighlight %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `capture` is the only way I was able to get this to work the way I wanted it to. All other variants (including `<div markdown="1">...</div>` incorrectly escaped content and/or added extra `</div>` tags at the end for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

highlight tag is made to preserve code indentation, just like the html pre tag does.

If you want correct a indentation, you must remove unwanted spacing.

The extra line is due to indentation before closing `{% endhighlight %}`. For liquid it's a new line.

Comment: you mean the jekyll do not have lie hear document `<<~EOS`? hear document `~` remove indent.

Comment: Code representation uses HTML PRE. This tag doesn't remove indentation. And no heredoc in liquid.