# Jekyll markdown strikethrough

Tags: markdown, jekyll, jekyll-bootstrap

I can't get Jekyll's markdown processor to listen to me.  These all display as is:

```
1.  ~Call Mom today.~

1.  ~~Call Mom today.~~
```

This just makes the internal text disappear:

```
1.  <s> Call Mom today.</s>
```

I'm using Jekyll Bootstrap pretty much out of the box.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Perhaps this

```sh
markdown: redcarpet
redcarpet:
  extensions: ["strikethrough"]
```

[Github flavored Markdown and pygments highlighting in Jekyll](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13464590)

Or

```sh
echo '1. <s>Call Mom today.</s>' | kramdown
```

Result

```htm
<ol>
  <li>
    <s>Call Mom today.</s>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Note if you are using `jekyll --watch` this config change will not be picked up; you will need to restart Jekyll.

Comment: Looks like I have a more general problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17004586/jekyll-markdown-deletes-any-html-in-list-item

Comment: +1 for the jekyll --watch note. That was tripping me up.

Comment: The `jekyll --watch` was key, especially since I had a separate watcher instance running in a different terminal and that was overwriting my output.

Comment: *“Note: Starting May 1st, 2016, GitHub Pages will only support kramdown.”* https://help.github.com/articles/updating-your-markdown-processor-to-kramdown/

Comment: Seems like Jekyll drops support for redcarpet and is kramdown only: https://jekyllrb.com/news/2019/08/20/jekyll-4-0-0-released/

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Jekyll with GitHub Pages then you will no longer be allowed to use redcarpet - [kramdown will only be supported](https://github.com/blog/2100-github-pages-now-faster-and-simpler-with-jekyll-3-0). So until kramdown supports "~~strikethough~~" with markdown I'm using a javascript to add strikethrough to page's text:

```
(function() {
  function strikethrough(){
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(
      /\~\~(.+?)\~\~/gim,
      '<del>$1</del>'
    );
  }
  strikethrough();
})();
```

Comment: " If you are currently using Rdiscount or Redcarpet we've enabled kramdown's GitHub-flavored Markdown support by default, meaning kramdown should have all the features of the two deprecated Markdown engines"

Comment: @djechlin Is there a config option I need to add to get ~~strikethough~~ working with kramdown on github-pages as it didn't work for me (after changing from redcarpet with strikethough extension)?

Comment: I don't know, I just quoted the page you linked.