# Maruku markdown deletes any html in list item

Tags: markdown, jekyll, maruku

Simple example here.

Source:

```
<span> hello </span>

1. <span> world </span>
```

Target:

```
<span> hello </span>
<ol>
<li />
</ol>
```

Seems to happen no matter what tag I use.  As far as I can tell from daring fireball's markdown documentation, this should be legal; span tags can appear anywhere.  I am on Jekyll and do not know what layer is responsible for this (bug in Jekyll's markdown renderer, my not using markdown correctly, etc.)  For good measure let's see what SO does with the same source:

hello

1. world

Looks like SO renders correctly.

This does not affect redcarpet or kramdown and appears to be a bug in Maruku.  Bug report submitted here: https://github.com/bhollis/maruku/issues/88

Leaving Jekyll tag as Maruku is the default markdown processor for Jekyll, and that's how I found this.

Comment: What renderer do you use (maruku (default), kramdown, redcarpet2)?

Comment: @Polygnome this happened both in maruku and after configuring `config.yml` to use redcarpet2.

Comment: @Polygnome and in kramdown.  Is this a problem in the, or in my understanding of, the markdown doc or spec?

Comment: @Polygnome ignore that; `jekyll --watch` doesn't seem to pick up changes from config, or at least this part of it.

Comment: Yes, `jekyll --watch` will not pick up changes in the _config.yml, you will need to restart jekyll for that.

Comment: @Polygnome seems to be a bug in Maruku.  Redcarpet seems fine.  If you want to post this as an answer (I would include info on --watch) I'll accept, otherwise I'll self-answer.

Comment: Technically I didn't post an answer, I just helped you find one, so it isn't my place to post it ;)