# Can Jekyll include source code from other sources than gist?

Tags: jekyll

I would like to include highlighted source code within a post.

I know that you can include a gist like this:

```
{% gist 5555251 %}
```

But can you also include arbitrary source code from a local file?

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways, a bit slow but easy just using something like http://highlightjs.org

Or you can use jekyll with pygments:

**Install:** `apt-get install python-pygments`
**configure in _config:** `pygments: true`
**Create the highlithing css:** `pygmentize -S default -f html > stylesheets/pygments.css`

Don't forget to load the css in your page!
source: http://www.stehem.net/2012/02/14/how-to-get-pygments-to-work-with-jekyll.html

Or you can use Github flavored Markdown:

**configure in _config:** `markdown: redcarpet`

I'm not sure but i think you need to install the redcarpet gem and pygments manually that it work.

source: [Github flavored Markdown and pygments highlighting in Jekyll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464590/github-flavored-markdown-and-pygments-highlighting-in-jekyll)

Use the SyntaxHighlighter-Plugin

- Include the source for [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/download/) you need at minimum: shCore.css, shThemeDefault.css and shCore.js
- Include for each language the corespondending shBrush.js like shBrushRuby.js for ruby
- Add at the end of your page `<script type="text/javascript">SyntaxHighlighter.all()</script>` to inizialize the plugin
- Wrap your code in {% SyntaxHighlighter lang %} and {% endSyntaxHighlighter %} replace lang by the language of your code
- Copy `SyntaxHighlighter.rb` in your `_plugins` folder

example project https://bitbucket.org/l33tname/jekyll-syntaxhighlighter/src

Comment: Is there a way I can use the `{% highlight %}`-tag with [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/contact.html) from Alex Gorbatchev?

Comment: I think its possible but for that you need to override the Liquid tag `highlight` or create your own tag http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#tags and as my knowing there is no plugin out there with the SyntaxHighlighter so I build one, I updating my question