# Jekyll Markdown processor similar to GitHub flavoured markdown

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I'm currently building a site using GitHub pages and trying to make use of some of the GitHub flavoured Markdown features. Specifically fenced code blocks and tables.

Using redcarpet I'm getting syntax highlighted fenced blocks but no tables.

Switching to kramdown gives tables but the previously working code blocks stop.

I'd prefer if I can get away without needing to run jekyll locally so I can update the site from anywhere.

Is there a configuration option that will configure either of the markdown processors to work in a similar fashion to GitHub flavoured markdown regarding the two above features?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use fenced code blocks and tables with kramdown.

Add this to your **_config.yml** to enable GitHub Flavoured Markdown for kramdown.

```
kramdown:
  input: GFM
```

Comment: That's a different issue then. Can you add the contents of your _config.yml to your question, please?

Comment: I found the same, while kramdown respected the backtick fenced code block it didn't highlight it with pygments. But as noted above, this is a separate issue.

Comment: There's [a great answer to the highlighting issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13614020/1287643).